# How to auto-generate stubs from mli file?

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have some interface file `mylib.mli` like

```
var foo      : 'a list -> int
val bar      : f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
val baz      : f:('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
val frobnitz : init:'acc -> f:('acc -> 'a -> 'acc) -> 'a list -> 'acc
val frobozz  : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
val quux     : 'a list list -> 'a list
```

Is there an automated way to generate the corresponding `mylib.ml` as a collection of stubs?  (By "stub" I mean a "minimal, interface-implementing function".)

Comment: Might be able to do it with a camlp5 extension...

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no such tool currently written. Maybe, because it is not a big work to do it manually. The easiest way to write a stub is:

```
let foo = failwith "not implemented"
```

or you can just make it in a following way

```
let stub _ = failwith "unimplemented"

let foo = stub
let bar = stub
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the -i flag of the compilers translates in the other direction.

```
$ cat stubs.ml
let foo (x: 'a list) = 3
let bar ~f: f l = List.map f l
let baz ~f: p l = List.filter p l
$ ocamlc -i stubs.ml
val foo : 'a list -> int
val bar : f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
val baz : f:('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

**Update**

Here's some interesting discussion in the context of Haskell:

> [Given a Haskell type signature, is it possible to generate the code automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205793/given-a-haskell-type-signature-is-it-possible-to-generate-the-code-automaticall)

Comment: yep, but good practice is to start from `*.mli`. And a better suggestion would be to use `corebuild stubs.inferred.mli`, imho.