# What is required to extend an Untyped Lambda calculus implementation to cover the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus?

Tags: haskell, scheme, lambda-calculus, system-f

[Matt Might](https://twitter.com/mattmight) talks about implementing a [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) interpreter in [7 lines of Scheme](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementing-a-programming-language/):

```
; eval takes an expression and an environment to a value
(define (eval e env) (cond
  ((symbol? e)       (cadr (assq e env)))
  ((eq? (car e) 'λ)  (cons e env))
  (else              (apply (eval (car e) env) (eval (cadr e) env)))))

; apply takes a function and an argument to a value
(define (apply f x)
  (eval (cddr (car f)) (cons (list (cadr (car f)) x) (cdr f))))

; read and parse stdin, then evaluate:
(display (eval (read) '())) (newline)
```

Now this is not the [Simply Typed Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Typed_lambda_calculus). In the [core of Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasgow_Haskell_Compiler#Architecture), there is an [Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) that bears a strong resemblance to [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F#Use_in_programming_languages). Some (including [Simon Peyton Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Peyton_Jones)) [have called this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmjvOLlCdFU) an implementation of the [Simply Typed Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus).

My question is: **What is required to extend an Untyped Lambda calculus implementation to cover the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus?**

Comment: System F is not STLC.

Comment: Simon Peyton Jones never called System F an implementation of simply typed lambda calculus. Furthermore, GHC's intermediate language has several important features System F lacks. Perhaps most prominent among them is general recursion (`Rec` and `letrec` forms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite unclear what you are asking, but I can think of a couple of valid answers:

- The representation will need to be changed to accomodate type annotations on the variables introduced by lambda abstractions.
- Depending on your representation, it might be possible to represent non-well-typed terms. If this is so, you'll want to implement a type checker.
- For evaluation, you don't need to change anything in your LC evaluator except to ignore the type annotations (that's the whole point of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)). However, if you write an evaluator that is basically `evalUntyped . eraseTypes`, you might have a harder time proving that it is total than if you write a bespoke `evalTyped` function.

Answer (score 1):

The simply typed lambda calculus (STLC) simply adds a type-checker to the system that you describe. That is, you can think of this evaluator as being the "run-time system" for the STLC.

Side node: type annotations are usually added to the language in order to simplify the job of the type checker, but they're not necessary.

Comment: Example of ... what? Are you asking me to implement the STLC type system in Scheme? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent answers above - and I have no intention of detracting from them.

In terms of implementing a type-checker - it is simpler in Haskell (although this could conceivably be ported to Scheme).

Here is a Simple Type checker in Haskell [that is an implementation](https://flippac.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/the-simply-typed-lambda-calculus-with-constraints/) of the [Simply Typed Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus):

```
type OType = ObjType (Fix ObjType)
type OEnvironment = Map TermIdentifier OType

check :: OEnvironment -> Term OType -> OType
check env (Var i) = case lookup i env of
                      Nothing -> error $ "Unbound variable " ++ i
                      Just v -> v
check env (App f p) = let t_f = check env f
                          t_p = check env p
                       in case t_f of
                            Fun (Fix t_p') (Fix r)
                              | t_p == t_p' -> r
                              | otherwise -> error "Parameter mismatch"
                            _ -> error "Applied a non-function"
check env (Lam i ty t) = let r = check (insert i ty env) t
                          in Fun (Fix ty) (Fix r)
```

Here is [another implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832145/15441) of the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus in Haskell:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$), (<$>))
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Safe (atMay)

data Type
    = Base
    | Arrow Type Type
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data Term
    = Const
    | Var Int -- deBruijn indexing; the nearest enclosing lambda binds Var 0
    | Lam Type Term
    | App Term Term
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

check :: [Type] -> Term -> Maybe Type
check env Const = return Base
check env (Var v) = atMay env v
check env (Lam ty tm) = Arrow ty <$> check (ty:env) tm
check env (App tm tm') = do
    Arrow i o <- check env tm
    i' <- check env tm'
    guard (i == i')
    return o

eval :: Term -> Term
eval (App tm tm') = case eval tm of
    Lam _ body -> eval (subst 0 tm' body)
eval v = v

subst :: Int -> Term -> Term -> Term
subst n tm Const = Const
subst n tm (Var m) = case compare m n of
    LT -> Var m
    EQ -> tm
    GT -> Var (m-1)
subst n tm (Lam ty body) = Lam ty (subst (n+1) tm body)
subst n tm (App tm' tm'') = App (subst n tm tm') (subst n tm tm'')

evalMay :: Term -> Maybe Term
evalMay tm = eval tm <$ check [] tm
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment with two links.