# Is there an effective way to generate a function given a generic (esp. with monads) type signature in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-theory, hindley-milner

I have already seen a variety of questions of the form "Given type signature `XXX`, find implementation in Haskell." Therefore it is natural to ask whether this can be generalized or algorithmized. A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205793/given-a-haskell-type-signature-is-it-possible-to-generate-the-code-automaticall). However, it is clear that generally this task is impossible. So the next question is to trade some generality for practicality.

> **Question**: Is the problem decidable if all the type signatures consists of rigid type variables together with some constraints, drawn from a fixed set (e.g. `Monad, Traversable, Foldable`?)

A typical problem would be `(Monad m) => (m j -> [m d]) -> m [j] -> [m [d]]`, where I used `[]` instead of `(..Constraints t) => t` for convenience.

Comment: Constraints can be desugared into dictionary passing so the problem is reduced to one without constraints, but types can be higher-rank, I'm pretty sure that makes the problem undecidable. The name of this class of problems is "proof search" if you want to start looking around.

Comment: Have you seen the ["Just do it"](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/735-The_magic_“Just_do_it”_type_class) typeclass?

Comment: Maybe the fixed set of constraints makes it still decidable after all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazingly enough, this is actually possible! Have a look at [Djinn](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/) (or you could compile [the executable](https://github.com/augustss/djinn) yourself), which implements this for you. For instance, given `f :: a -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b -> c) -> c`, Djinn outputs `f a b c = c a (b a)` (amongst other possibilities). You can find more examples (with the command-line version) at http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1178. Unfortunately it doesn’t support typeclasses though, but I wouldn’t rule out another tool that I haven’t found which does support them.

(If you’re interested in how this works, read up about the *Curry-Howard Isomorphism*, which states that a program in a language such as Haskell is equivalent to a proof. For instance, writing an implementation for `f :: a -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b -> c) -> c` is equivalent to proving the statement ‘given a proposition `a`, then if `a` implies `b`, and `a` and `b` together imply `c`, then `c` is true’. Because of this, you can use an automated prover to figure out the implementation and then just mechanically translate this into code to get an implementation.)